# Ajax success data not appending to input values

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im on this self-teaching jQuery curve. I'm trying to pass data on ajax success but the data is not being appended. I read in the documentation that it has something to do with `callback()` and functions being asynchronous. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around that. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<div style="display:none;" id="callReport">
 <input id="demo" type="text">
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: 'demo.php',
                data: valuesforms,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //show callreport div
                    $('#callReport').show();

                    //append to callReport input
                    $('#demo').val(data.demo);

                    //test check if empty
                    console.log(data.demo);//not empty ok

                }

            });
```

Comment: Add an error handler `error: function(jxkr) { console.log(jxkr)}, success: function (data)
                {...`

Comment: might be useful to log 'data' to see whats actually returned. I don't like to use the json as a datatype because it can silently return nothing. I like to return a string and them parse the json mysel. Saves lots of headaches.

Answer (score -1):

(data.demo)

This means you are expecting json and the **First thing** you have to do is to parse using JSON.parse(data)

Second, Make sure demo.php is returning JSON correctly